# Check if something is in each row (row length>1)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

Basically I have a matrix and row with a in it I want to append a "1" to a list, otherwise append a "0"

The code is as follows:

```
is.there.A <- function(a,b,c,d,e) {

  library(combinat)
  x <- c(a,b,c,d,e)  
  matrix <- matrix(combn(x,3), ncol=3, byrow=T) 
  row <- nrow(matrix)
  list <- list()
  
  for (i in seq(row)) {

    if (matrix[i,] %in% "A") {c(list, "1")}

    else {c(list, "0")} 

    print(list)

    }

}
```

But it doesn't work and this shows up.

Warning messages:

> 1: In if (matrix[i, ] %in% "A") { :
>
> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

The question is how to overcome this to achieve the objective

Comment: why aren't you using ifelse? Also you have %in% backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid your explicit loop by using `apply`

```
is.there.A <- function(a,b,s,d,e) {

  library(combinat)
  x <- c(a,b,s,d,e)  
  .matrix <- matrix(combn(x,3), ncol=3, byrow=T) 

  any_A <- apply(.matrix, 1, `%in%`, x = 'A')
  as.list(as.numeric(any_A))

}
```

Never grow an object within a for loop, pre-allocate then fill.

Avoid naming objects with function names (eg `c` or `matrix` or`list`)

Answer (score 1):

You meant to test for `"A" %in% matrix[i,]`, not the other way around. However, note that

```
row <- nrow(matrix)
list <- list()
for (i in seq(row)) {
   if ("A" %in% matrix[i,]) {c(list, "1")}
   else {c(list, "0")}
}
```

can be rewritten

```
rowSums(matrix == "A") > 0
```

It returns a vector of logicals (TRUE/FALSE) which is the most appropriate output for your function. However, if you really need a list of '1' or '0', you can wrap it as follows:

```
as.list(ifelse(rowSums(matrix == "A") > 0, "1", "0"))
```

Also note that it is a bad idea to name an object `matrix` since it is also the name of a function in R.